# undefined method `name' for ["Yes", true]:Array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I acctual don't know where Array ["Yes",true] came from. I have two models like this:

```
GeneralExam has_many topic_questions

TopicQuestion belongs to general_exam, belongs_to topic
```

In TopicQuestion, I have columns: general_exam_id, topic_id, number_question, to store a number question for each topic in general exam.

I built a nested form for create new general exam, on form I built a dynamic select, when user choose a course from a dropdown list, I have other dropdown lists to display topics of course chosen by user.

This is my javascript code for dynamic select:

```
<% content_for :head do %>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#general_exam_course_id').change(function () {
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "<%= update_topics_general_exams_path %>",
          data: { course_id: $('#general_exam_course_id').val() },
          dataType: "script"
        });
      });
    </script>
<% end %>
```

`#general_exam_course_id` is **ID** of dropdown list for select course. `update_topics_general_exams_path` is route to my `update` action in general exam controller, this is my `update` action:

```
  def update_topics
    @course = Course.find(params[:course_id])
    @topics = @course.topics
  end
```

I have a `update_topics.js.erb` also:

```
$('div#topic_questions select').html("<%= j options_from_collection_for_select(@topics, 'id', 'name') %>");
```

Dropdown lists in `div#topic_questions`  will get `@topics` value from `update_topics` action (I think so) and display it. When I create new general exam, it's ok. But when I press `Edit` link, it show me an error which I don't know why and where it comes:

```
NoMethodError in General_exams#edit
undefined method `name' for ["Yes", true]:Array

Extracted source (around line #3):

1: <div class="row">
2:  <div class="span6"><%= remove_child_link "Remove below topic", f %></div><br><br>
3:  <div class="span3"><%= f.association :topic, collection: @topics, label_method: :name, value_method: :id, prompt: "Choose a topic", label: false %></div>
4:  <%= f.input :number_question, placeholder: 'Number of questions', label: false, style: 'display: inline' %>
5: </div>
```

My `edit` action only have: `@general_exam = GeneralExam.find(params[:id])`. I don't know why `topic` association field of general exam display an Array ["Yes", true]. I don't have it, don't define it any where, why it come when I edit general exam?

**Update**

If I remove `label_method: :name, value_method: :id` in:

```
<%= f.association :topic, collection: @topics, label_method: :name, value_method: :id, prompt: "Choose a topic", label: false %>
```

The page is not error, but Dropdown lists have value `Yes, No` in select, not the name of topic I have created for exam. Form can get the number question of each topic, but it can not get name of topic.

When I create:

[image]

When I edit:

[image]

I found this in `config/locales/simple_form.en.yml`:

```
en:
  simple_form:
    "yes": 'Yes'
    "no": 'No'
```

Is this a problem?

**Update: Don't pass @topics in new action but it's still have on new page When course even is not selected yet**

My new action:

```
  def new
    @general_exam = GeneralExam.new
    5.times { @general_exam.topic_questions.build }
    #@topics = Topic.all
  end
```

As in my extract source above, I have below code in new, edit too (use same form):

```
<%= f.association :topic, collection: @topics, label_method: :name, value_method: :id, prompt: "Choose a topic", label: false %>
```

So I don't pass @topics, but when I go to new page, dropdown lists for topic still display `Yes, No` value.

Comment: What is the result if you type on the rails console : course = Course.find.first  and then puts course.topics  ?

Comment: @QumaraotBurgas are you mean `course = Course.first`? I run it, then `puts course.topics`, it returned: `#<Topic:0xb952954>
#<Topic:0xbb0d9b0> => nil`

Comment: I have a feeling , that your model Topic doesn't return an instance object with a method 'name' and returns an array ['Yes',true]. try to iterate on the collection course.topics on the console like this : course.topics.each do |c| (new line ) puts c.name (new line)  end . Or : course.topics.each {|c| puts c.name}

Comment: @QumaraotBurgas  It returns name of topics of course: 
`Integrated Management
Basic Management... 
`. One more strange thing, in my new action, I don't have `@topics` variable, but when I go to new page, Dropdown lists for topics still display Yes, No. I think it have to error because I don't pass `@topics` in my new action, but it's not.

Comment: For booleans, use checkboxes.

Comment: My topics don't have what values is boolean, and I display in dropdown list is name of topic.

Comment: If you take a look at the [simple_form wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form) , you'll see , that there is no need to pass a collection , it takes a name of association field , looks at the models and here you go. Try to define the collection for the dropdown inline , something like: :collection => Company.active.all(:order => 'name') .

Comment: @QumaraotBurgas I passed `collection: Topic.limit(5)`, it really get 5 topics.

Comment: What about :collection => @your_edit_choice.topics ?

Comment: @QumaraotBurgas what is `@your_edit_choice`? It seems working when i set limit 5 topic, when I try update general exam, it display topics I have created for exam. And when I create new general exam, if form has error and new page was rendered again, it kept topics are selected.

Comment: I meant if you are selecting the course for edit first , then you should filter only topics , belonging to that couse , right ? That's why I said "your edit choice" . Take a look on the i18n at the wiki also , it seems there are specific parts .

Comment: @QumaraotBurgas What is this related to i18n :| ? I think I will make a small tip, I will set Topic.limit(1), and hide dropdown list for topics. When user choose course, they will be displayed. So user can't see what value when they aren't choose course yet. I think that is my solution for it can work now. Thanks for your help, special when you suggest me add another collection for `f.association :topic` :D

Comment: I believe I have the correct answer for you below ↓

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok , our time for comments chat-like is over :)(the System suggested to move to the chat room ) . The solution it seems to be passing the collection inline in the association of the simple_form :

```
<%= f.association :topic, collection: @topics, label_method: :name, value_method: :id, prompt: "Choose a topic", label: false %>
```

becomes :

```
<%= f.association :topic, collection: Topic.limit(1), prompt: "Choose a topic", label: false %>
```

It would work for now , I think .

Comment: I have used `<%= f.association :topic, collection: Topic.limit(1), prompt: "Choose a topic", label: false %>`. But it's has some small problem like when I submit and forget fill some field, form has error, render new page again, dropdown lists did not kept selected topics. But, you helped me solve problem in question :)

Comment: In case you are interested : [Railscast on the topic](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised) .

Comment: This is second nested form in my app, before I built question-answers nested form, it's works ok, but this second has some problem, althrough the way to implement is the same :( But, I think I will use client validation so user can not submit form when fields are blank, so it will not render page again and lost topics selected :D

Answer (score 1):

You've got the right idea by assigning your query to `@topics` and passing it to your view... but, you're putting it in the wrong actions and not passing them to the right views:

```
def update_topics
  @course = Course.find(params[:course_id])
  @topics = @course.topics
end
```

-

### What you should do:

There is NO `update view` for your update action, so, you must place the following 2 lines:

```
@course = Course.find(params[:course_id])
@topics = @course.topics
```

in both your `new` action and your `edit` action

Then you can go ahead and use your original simple_form code, which IS/WAS ORIGINALLY correct:

```
<%= f.association :topic, collection: @topics, 
                  label_method: :name, value_method: :id, 
                  prompt: "Choose a topic", label: false 
%>
```

Alternatively, you could *SKIP* the @topics in your controllers and simply put the following in your views:

**new** view

```
<%= f.association :topic, collection: Topics.all, 
                  label_method: :name, value_method: :id, 
                  prompt: "Choose a topic", label: false 
%>
```

**edit** view

```
<%= f.association :topic, collection: Course.find(params[:course_id]).topics, 
                  label_method: :name, value_method: :id, 
                  prompt: "Choose a topic", label: false 
%>
```

*NOTE* the difference:

- I would think that in your `new` view you would want the user to see ALL possible topics.
- While in your `edit` view you just want them to see the topics for this course, correct?

-

### Why it happened:

1. Since, you were not passing ANY collection earlier, there was no 'name' method/column for simple_form to use as the labels/display values in the dropdown and thus the error message you got regarding `Array ["Yes",true]`
2. If/when you removed the `label_method: :name, value_method: :id,` options you probably would have seen as many choices as you had expected rows in the dropdown, but instead of a list of the course topic names you would have seen a list of Topic objects (something like this):

   > ```
   > #<Topic::xxxx>
   > #<Topic::xxxx>
   > ...
   > #<Topic::xxxx>
   > ```
3. And, when you don't supply the collection, you get only 2 yes/no values which is the simple_form default per the config file you found (`config/locales/simple_form.en.yml`).
4. So, as you might have guessed by now, this is why what you finally used...

   > ```
   > <%= f.association :topic, collection: 
   >                   Topic.limit(1), 
   >                   prompt: "Choose a topic", 
   >                   label: false 
   > %>
   > ```

   ...kind of "worked" as a workaround -- because it ***did*** execute a proper query and supplied it to the simple_form, but it limited the results to only the **first** topic in the table (without any ordering/sort)

At least, this is what I have learned/gone through. HTH!